# Dynamic ActiveRecord Associations (based on another model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'd like to do something like this:

```
  class Store < ApplicationRecord
    Product.select(:category).distinct do |p|
      has_one "lowest_"+p.category+"_price".to_sym, -> { where(category: p.category).order(price: :asc) }, class_name: "Product"
    end
  end
```

But rails seems to ignore the lines are there.  When I replace `Product.select(:category).distinct` with a hardcoded array it works fine, but then it's not dynamic.

I imagine this is some kind of initialization issue, but is there a solution?  I'm thinking I can write an initializer, but I'm not sure how to apply an association after the class has been created.  There may just be a straight ruby answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something wrong with your code, it isn't doing what you expect it to.

```
"lowest_"+p.category+"_price".to_sym
```

Is only converting `"_price"` to a symbol.

I would also use `pluck` instead, since you don't need your `Product` model here.

Try doing this instead:

```
class Store < ApplicationRecord
  Product.pluck(:category).uniq do |category|
    has_one "lowest_#{category}_price".to_sym, -> { where(category: category).order(price: :asc) }, class_name: Product
  end
end
```

Comment: That worked, but what was my query doing?  I thought it was returning Product instances and I was calling `p.category` to get the category string.

Comment: More investigation, looks like string interpolation was my big mistake.  Not sure why I didn't see errors earlier... It was converting "_price" to a symbol and failing.